# Как сделать снимок экрана в буфер на C++?

Tags: c++, windows, screenshots

Нужно сделать снимок экрана и записать его RGB-данные в буфер (BYTE*, unsigned char*, string - не важно). Не нужно сохранять файл, не нужны BMP-заголовки - просто массив RGB.

**Как это сделать на C++ с минимально возможным временем выполнения и наименьшими затратами системных ресурсов?**

*PS: среда выполнения - Windows.
Пробовал glReadPixels() - но в результате чёрный экран. GDI работает медленно и я так и не понял как с его помощью достать RGB. И курсор мыши GDI не захватывает*

Comment: какая платформа?

Comment: В c++ нет встроенных средств для работы с изображениями, или снятия копии экрана в частности. Укажите под какой ОС Вы работаете, и какие библиотеки используете.

Comment: Среда - Windows. По библиотекам хотелось бы получить консультацию - в вопросе я добавил описание проблем, с которыми столкнулся

Comment: `getDC(0)` - даёт контекст экрана и его можно копировать. Вот пример http://www.cyberforum.ru/win-api/thread877306.html в нете.

Comment: Я знаю про GetDC, CreateCompatibleDC, BitBlt... Как из этого всего извлечь строковый буфер значений RGB???

Comment: GlReadPixels будет работать "лучше" в контексте OpenGL окна, она не предназначена работать с GDI или GDI+ к сожалению.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил пока так, при помощи средств gdi32:

```
void CaptureScreen(){
// Определение контекстов
HDC ScreenDC = GetDC(0);
HDC MemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(ScreenDC);

// Фиксация размеров экрана
int ScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
int ScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

// Создание и частичное заполнение структуры формата
BITMAPINFO BMI;
BMI.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
BMI.bmiHeader.biWidth = ScreenWidth;
BMI.bmiHeader.biHeight = -ScreenHeight; // Отрицательное значение высоты, чтобы изображение не было перевёрнутым
BMI.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = ScreenWidth * ScreenHeight * 3; // Ширина * Высота * Количество_цветов_на_пиксель
BMI.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
BMI.bmiHeader.biBitCount  = 24;
BMI.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;

ScreenshotSize = BMI.bmiHeader.biSizeImage; // ScreenshotSize - глобальная переменная типа int, может меняться в ходе выполнения программы
unsigned char *ImageBuffer; // Указатель на блок данных BGR, управляемый HBITMAP (да, именно BGR - не RGB)
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(ScreenDC,&BMI,DIB_RGB_COLORS,(void**)&ImageBuffer,0,0);
SelectObject(MemoryDC, hBitmap);
BitBlt(MemoryDC, 0, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, ScreenDC , 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

// Контексты больше не нужны
DeleteDC(MemoryDC);
ReleaseDC(NULL, ScreenDC);

// Если требуется RGB вместо BGR - следующий цикл перевернёт нужные байты
for(int i = 0; i < ScreenshotSize; i += 3){
    unsigned char ColorValue = ImageBuffer[i];
    ImageBuffer[i] = ImageBuffer[i + 2];
    ImageBuffer[i + 2] = ColorValue;
}

// Используем ImageBuffer как нам хочется... после удаляем его хендлер (HBITMAP) для избежания утечки памяти
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
}
```

Быстрее, наверно, будет только DirectX или OpenGL, но с последним уже был неудачный опыт скриншота, и я пока не знаю как получить данные прямо из графического вывода

Comment: Указатель `ImageBuffer` должен быть предварительно подготовлен, т.е. на момент вызова `CreateDIBSection` там должен лежать валидный указатель на блок памяти нужного размера. Если у вас программа при CreateDIBSection не падает, то вам очень везет. Соответственно, если у вас блок памяти не выделен, то что вы пытаетесь удалять при помощи delete?

Comment: По поводу скорости - вряд ли средствами WinAPI удастся сделать быстрее. Я бы сказал - этот способ, наоборот, *сравнительно* быстрый (если сравнивать с тем же GetPixel).

Comment: Я тупил - удалял ImageBuffer вместо DeleteObject(hBitmap). Теперь всё чётко работает и память не утекает. Но всё же мучает вопрос, неужели нельзя захватить то, что видишь на мониторе, с помощью OpenGL?

Comment: с помощью OpenGL по идее можно, но я с ним не работал)

Comment: Оказывается я забыл, как CreateDIBSection работает. Да, все верно, память заранее не нужно выделать, сама функция положит в ImageBuffer указатель на блок данных. А потом только сделать DeleteObject для объекта hBitmap.

Answer (score 4):

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112482/c-getting-rgb-from-hbitmap):

```
/* Globals */
int ScreenX = GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(0), HORZRES);
int ScreenY = GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(0), VERTRES);
BYTE* ScreenData = new BYTE[3*ScreenX*ScreenY];

void ScreenCap() {
HDC hdc = GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());
HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC (hdc);
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, ScreenX, ScreenY);
BITMAPINFOHEADER bmi = {0};
bmi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmi.biPlanes = 1;
bmi.biBitCount = 24;
bmi.biWidth = ScreenX;
bmi.biHeight = -ScreenY;
bmi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bmi.biSizeImage = ScreenX * ScreenY;
SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, ScreenX, ScreenY, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
GetDIBits(hdc, hBitmap, 0, ScreenY, ScreenData, (BITMAPINFO*)&bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

DeleteDC(hdcMem);
ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
}

inline int PosR(int x, int y) {
return ScreenData[3*((y*ScreenX)+x)+2];
}

inline int PosG(int x, int y) {
return ScreenData[3*((y*ScreenX)+x)+1];
}

inline int PosB(int x, int y) {
return ScreenData[3*((y*ScreenX)+x)];
}
```

Comment: Cоответственно цвет пискеля через PosR, PosG, PosB

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать через COLORREF и GetPixel, т.е получить дисплейный контекст через GetDC, а потом через GetPixel прочитать цвет пикселя.

```
HDC dc = GetDC();
COLORREF color = GetPixel(dc,x,y);
```

Comment: Если нужно изображение целиком, то вместо `GetPixel` лучше использовать `BitBlt`.

Comment: GetPixel кажется легко и просто, но работает адски долго. 400 байт оно получало пару секунд, а дисплей FullHD 4 млн. байт - прога тупо висла когда я получал пиксели в цикле.

Comment: Такие вещи надо в отдельном потоке делать