# Блокировка скриншотов - какая программа это может делать?

Tags: windows, gdi, screenshots

Не уверен точно, что тут работает именно блокировка, но...

Написанный мной клиент может (и должен по заданию) транслировать по сети скрины рабочего стола сотрудников. Скриншот делается обычными средствами GDI, алгоритм в [этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/627095/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c).

При просмотре у одного из сотрудников наблюдается такая картина:[image: ScrnLock]

То есть просто чёрный фон, но справа внизу, пробиваясь через все запреты, светится всем знакомая надпись от Microsoft... Судя по ней я предположил, что скрины блокируются, так как данный сотрудник в этот момент работает, и у других такого нет.

**Собственно вопрос: не ошибаюсь ли я насчёт блокировки, и, если нет, какой софт может такое делать?**

Comment: Активируйте сотруднику Windows

Comment: Да полофиса на не активированных сидит и ничего - транслируют без проблем. Хоть значок корзины то должен быть, но там просто чёрный экран

Comment: @Iceman: Ну, на неактивированной версии всякие штуки имеют право не работать. Так что вы всё же активируйте и сравните, работает в этом случае или нет.

Comment: По поводу активации дополню, что легче всего (в будущем) поднять свой kms и активировать через него. Серверная винда умеет это делать в качестве роли.

Comment: @donRumata для KMS нужно не менее 25 разных клиентских машин, подключение одной и той же 25 раз подряд не поможет. Их может просто не быть в таком количестве, так что вариант не слишком уиверсальный.

Comment: @rdorn, лично настраивал кмс на 12-м сервере. И могу сказать, что из всех уникальных идентификаторов, которые есть в системе достаточно поменять хостнейм. Я это всё провернул через виртуалбокс, снапшоты и Runonce скрипт в виртуалке с виндой. Раскочегарил kms буквально за пару часов.

Comment: @donRumata забавно, а я, в своё время, из-за этого лимита отказался от KMS, благо MAC-ов было много свободных. Буду знать, спасибо. Получается MS перехитрили сами себя... Как с терминальными лицензиями

Comment: @rdorn, мы МАК исчерпали. Если интересно - могу скинуть свою быдлореализацию по введению кмс в нормальное функционирование.