# Как можно сделать скриншот на C++?

Tags: c++, screenshots, скриншот

Мне нужно закинуть его в буфер (если такой есть) или массив, проанализировать его и в зависимости от того, что там есть, нажать мышкой по координатам.
Нужно делать скриншот с определённой периодичностью, какая нужна команда и библиотека?
Если записываются данные в двумерный массив (A[X][Y] = цвет;) тогда всё ок.
Если записываются в какой-то буфер нужна команда чтобы узнать цвет пикселя по определённым координатам.

C++ Пользуюсь недавно, комментарии к командам приветствуются (использую Visual Studio).

Comment: Посмотрите [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/746167/195342), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/627095/195342)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC hdcCompatible = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);

    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, width, height);
    HGDIOBJ hOld = SelectObject(hdcCompatible, hBitmap);

    BitBlt(hdcCompatible, 0, 0, width, height, hdcScreen, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    BITMAPINFO bmi;
    ZeroMemory(&bmi, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = height;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    int** pixels = new int*[height];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        pixels[i] = new int[width];
    }

    GetDIBits(hdcScreen, hBitmap, 0, height, (LPVOID*)pixels, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    SelectObject(hdcCompatible, hOld);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    DeleteDC(hdcCompatible);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);

    // Теперь мы можем использовать массив pixels для анализа скриншота.

    return 0;
}
```

Чтобы получить цвет пикселя по координатам (x, y), вы можете использовать следующую функцию:

```
int getPixelColor(int x, int y, int** pixels) {
    return pixels[y][x];
}
```

Comment: а можете пожалуйста объяснить, что идёт после строчки
`int height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);`
я пытался найти информацию о HDC но так ничего и не понял, буду очень благодарен, если для каждой строчки будут комментарии

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdc